# aws apigateway update-integration cli error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am copying an exact example from aws to upload an integration request base mapping to my api via the cli and I am getting an error.

This is the command:
`aws apigateway update-integration --rest-api-id a1b2c3d4e5 --resource-id a1b2c3 --http-method POST --patch-operations op='replace',path='/requestTemplates/application~1json',value='{"example": "json"}'`

and this is the error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--patch-operations': Expected: '=', received: '"' for input:
op=add,path=/requestTemplates/application~1json,value={"example": "json"}
                                                       ^
```

This is where I found the command:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-integration.html

What is going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the solution, wrap the command in quotes:

```
aws apigateway update-integration --rest-api-id a1b2c3d4e5 --resource-id a1b2c3 --http-method POST --patch-operations "op='replace',path='/requestTemplates/application~1json',value='{"example": "json"}'"
```

AWS should update their example

Comment: Thanks for this! AWS still need to update their examples though ಠ_ಠ